# CSS grid with BIG gap (gap set to 0)

Tags: html, css

So, I wanted to make a calculator app and I ran across this problem with display: grid. There was a **HUGE** gap between each element.

Image:

[image: big horizontal gap]

I'm very confused. I have no idea what to do.

I tried removing container from the main div. I tried using gap: 0 and gap: 1px but nothing worked. I got the code from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Seven Segment";
  src: url("../fonts/7seg/Seven\ Segment.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Livvic:wght@200&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: Livvic, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 0.25px;
}


/* Boring CSS Extra Styles AASKLSYHAKLDJHS */

.calc-key {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 250ms;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.calc-key:hover,
.calc-key:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 4px 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.calc-key:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.calc-key:active {
  background-color: #F0F0F1;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 2px 4px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<title>Calculator</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<script src="./js/scripts.js" defer></script>
<div id="calc container container-fluid">
  <div class="display">0</div>
</div>
<div class="keys">
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(0)">0</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(1)">1</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(2)">2</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(3)">3</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(4)">4</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(5)">5</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(6)">6</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(7)">7</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(8)">8</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(9)">9</div>
  <div class="calc-key">AC</div>
  <div class="calc-key" style="background:rgb(255,75,75)">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: css is easy with tailwind .. https://tailwindcss.com/

Comment: @M.Ismail That is not helpful

Comment: Add something like `max-width:400px;` to the .keys

Comment: @M.Ismail Saying it twice does not make it more helpful, just annoying

Comment: What is the desired layout you want then? Do you want the individual grid items to grow to 33.3% width? Or you want them to remain at the same size and the grid parent's width to "shrink fit" its content?

Comment: `display:grid` is a bit like `display:block` in the sense that it takes up the width of it's parent if not restricted in another way. So like @mplungjan suggests, restrict the width of the grid element.

Comment: @mplungjan
    twice is just a network issue... one is deleted already .. and the other is just a comment for any one didn`t know about tailwind.

Comment: For responsiveness purposes, you could remove the `width/height` properties from `.calc-key` and control their size with scaling the entire 'keypad' relative to the current parent or viewport size. Parent `inline-grid` would work instead, but that might pose responsiveness issues later on. Also, try using `display: grid; place-items: center;` to center key content instead of flexbox. Just a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your desired result is, you could set `keys` to have a `display` of `inline-grid` like so:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Seven Segment";
  src: url("../fonts/7seg/Seven\ Segment.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Livvic:wght@200&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: Livvic, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 0.25px;
}


/* Boring CSS Extra Styles AASKLSYHAKLDJHS */

.calc-key {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 250ms;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.calc-key:hover,
.calc-key:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 4px 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.calc-key:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.calc-key:active {
  background-color: #F0F0F1;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 2px 4px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<title>Calculator</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<script src="./js/scripts.js" defer></script>
<div id="calc container container-fluid">
  <div class="display">0</div>
</div>
<div class="keys">
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(0)">0</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(1)">1</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(2)">2</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(3)">3</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(4)">4</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(5)">5</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(6)">6</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(7)">7</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(8)">8</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(9)">9</div>
  <div class="calc-key">AC</div>
  <div class="calc-key" style="background:rgb(255,75,75)">C</div>
</div>
```

or you could remove the `width` from the grid items:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Seven Segment";
  src: url("../fonts/7seg/Seven\ Segment.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Livvic:wght@200&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: Livvic, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 0.25px;
}


/* Boring CSS Extra Styles AASKLSYHAKLDJHS */

.calc-key {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 250ms;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 100px;
}

.calc-key:hover,
.calc-key:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 4px 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.calc-key:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.calc-key:active {
  background-color: #F0F0F1;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 2px 4px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<title>Calculator</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<script src="./js/scripts.js" defer></script>
<div id="calc container container-fluid">
  <div class="display">0</div>
</div>
<div class="keys">
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(0)">0</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(1)">1</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(2)">2</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(3)">3</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(4)">4</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(5)">5</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(6)">6</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(7)">7</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(8)">8</div>
  <div class="calc-key" onclick="update(9)">9</div>
  <div class="calc-key">AC</div>
  <div class="calc-key" style="background:rgb(255,75,75)">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline-grid worked. thanks a lot!